# How to iterate nested map in velocity template?

Tags: java, html, hashmap, velocity

How to iterate nested map in velocity template?
I have

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, List<MealPlanGroup>>>> termPlans=new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, List<MealPlanGroup>>>>();
```

this map i filled data in java and render to html page but not able to iterate on html page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you have that scary variable bound to `termPlans` variable inside a template, you could do the following:

```
#foreach( $level1 in $termPlans )
    <!-- Iterating over the values of the first Map level -->
    #foreach( $level2 in $level1 )
        <!-- Iterating over the values of the second Map level -->
        #foreach( $list in $level2 )
            <!-- Iterating over the values of the third Map level -->
            #foreach( $mealPlanGroup in $list )
                <!-- Iterating over the values of the List -->
                $mealPlanGroup.id <br/>
            #end
        #end
    #end
#end
```

This would only use maps values and it would ignore their keys. If you also need the keys, you could try iterating over `entrySet()`:

```
#foreach( $level1Entry in $termPlans.entrySet() )
    <!-- Iterating over the values of the first Map level -->
    Level 1 key is $level1Entry.getKey()

    #foreach( $level2Entry in $level1Entry.getValue().entrySet() )
        Level 2 key is $level2Entry.getKey()

        <!-- Iterating over the values of the second Map level -->
        #foreach( $level3Entry in $level2Entry.getValue().entrySet() )
            Level 3 key is $level3Entry.getKey()

            <!-- Iterating over the values of the third Map level -->
            #foreach( $mealPlanGroup in $level3Entry.getValue() )
                <!-- Iterating over the values of the List -->
                $mealPlanGroup.id <br/>
            #end
        #end
    #end
#end
```

Comment: Could you please provide the key and value iteration

Comment: not able to iterate key and value pair could you please send code

Comment: All `.getKey()` and `.getValue()` getters can be replaced by `.key` and `.value`, Velocity will automatically call the getter.