# How can I iterate a map having key as string and value as map again?

Tags: java, velocity

How can I iterate below map in velocity and get value from it.

`HashMap<String,Map<String, String>> mapobj = new HashMap<>();`

Considering above map which i am passing in velocity template, below is the velocity template code which i am using to get values from above map, but it is not working

```
 #foreach ($mapEntry in $map.keySet())
        #foreach ($map1 in $mapEntry.values())
            #set($str1='loanType')
            <td>$map1.get($str1)</td>
        #end
    #end
```

Below code also I have tried but it is also not working.

```
 #foreach ($mapEntry in $map)
        #foreach ($map1 in $mapEntry.entrySet())
            #set($str1='loanType')
            <td>$map1.get($str1)</td>
        #end
    #end
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? Are you facing any issue?

Comment: You iterate through this the exact same way you iterate through any other map, there is absolutely nothing special here.

Comment: You can try nested foreach to iterate inner map.

Comment: @AmitBera :  #foreach ($mapEntry in $map.keySet())
  #foreach ($map1 in $mapEntry.values())
   #set($str1='loanType')
   <td>$map1.get($str1)</td>
  #end
    #end this is the code which i am using in velocity template for printing data from the map I shown in the post. I also have updated the post.

Comment: Possible Duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45161586/how-to-iterate-nested-map-in-velocity-template

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate nested map in velocity template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45161586/how-to-iterate-nested-map-in-velocity-template)